# argparse mutually exclusive group title and description in help message

Tags: python, argparse

Why I can't I have an `argparse` mutually exclusive group with a `title` or `description`, so that it appears as a separate category under the `--help` message?

I have an options group with a name and a description:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group = parser.add_argument_group(
    'foo options', 'various (mutually exclusive) ways to do foo')
group.add_argument('--option_a', action='store_true', help='option a')
group.add_argument('--option_b', action='store_true', help='option b')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Output of `--help`:

```
usage: foo.py [-h] [--option_a] [--option_b]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

foo options:
  various (mutually exclusive) ways to do foo

  --option_a  option a
  --option_b  option b
```

But I want to make the group mutually exclusive:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()  # here
group.add_argument('--option_a', action='store_true', help='option a')
group.add_argument('--option_b', action='store_true', help='option b')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Output of `--help`:

```
usage: foo.py [-h] [--option_a | --option_b]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --option_a  option a
  --option_b  option b
```

There is no distinction in the help message that these options are part of a group, and I can't specify a title/description (add_mutually_exclusive_group takes no additional positional arguments). Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Have you looked at argparse subcommands?https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why?  Because that's how it's coded!

Mutually exclusive groups are a subclass of ArgumentGroups, but the interface is different.  Purpose is also quite different.  An argument group controls the display of the help lines.  It does nothing to parsing.  A mutually exclusive group checks arguments during parsing, and is used when formatting the usage line.  But it has no effect on the help lines.

But it is possible to embed a mutually exclusive group in an argument group (but not the other way around).  That should produce what you want.

```
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: group = parser.add_argument_group(
   ...:  'foo options', 'various (mutually exclusive) ways to do foo')
In [4]: mxg = group.add_mutually_exclusive_group() 
In [5]: mxg.add_argument('--option_a', action='store_true', help='option a');
In [6]: mxg.add_argument('--option_b', action='store_true', help='option b');

In [7]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--option_a | --option_b]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

foo options:
  various (mutually exclusive) ways to do foo

  --option_a  option a
  --option_b  option b
```

There are more details in the code itself, and in a bug/issue or two, but this should get you going.

Comment: I'm seeing a possible bug in argparse (or I could just be doing it wrong...) your answer works great at the top level, but fails if the data is in a parent parser ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066374/python-argparse-mutually-exclusive-group-and-add-argument-group-in-a-parent-proc

Comment: @Paul T., yes the parents mechanism does not handle this kind of group nesting. There might even be a bug/issue about it.