Argparse How to add mutually exclusive group to argument group help text used as parent parser for all subparsers
The argparse docs refer to an example of how to add a mutually exclusive group to an argument group to add title/description to those arguments. However, when used in parents to subparsers the mutually exclusive group is left out of the argument group help text description.
This snippet code:
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parent_parser = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent_parser.add_argument('--common')
parent_parser_group = parent_parser.add_argument_group('New Group', 'Description.')
parent_parser_group.add_argument('--non-mut')
meg = parent_parser_group.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
meg.add_argument('--mut1', dest='mut')
meg.add_argument('--mut2', dest='mut')

parser = ArgumentParser(description='The main parser.')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subcommand', required=True)

command1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command1', parents=[parent_parser])
command1_parser.add_argument('--c1')

command2_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command2', parents=[parent_parser])
command2_parser.add_argument('--c2')

command1_parser.print_help()

Prints out
usage: argparse_debug.py command1 [-h] [--common COMMON] [--non-mut NON_MUT] [--mut1 MUT | --mut2 MUT] [--c1 C1]

options:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --common COMMON
  --mut1 MUT
  --mut2 MUT
  --c1 C1

New Group:
  Description.

  --non-mut NON_MUT

But I was expecting
usage: argparse_debug.py command1 [-h] [--common COMMON] [--non-mut NON_MUT] [--mut1 MUT | --mut2 MUT] [--c1 C1]

options:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --common COMMON
  --c1 C1

New Group:
  Description.

  --mut1 MUT
  --mut2 MUT
  --non-mut NON_MUT

Also note that parent_parser.print_help() has the expected behavior, so something is lost when set as a parent.
usage: argparse_debug.py [--common COMMON] [--non-mut NON_MUT] [--mut1 MUT | --mut2 MUT]

options:
  --common COMMON

New Group:
  Description.

  --non-mut NON_MUT
  --mut1 MUT
  --mut2 MUT

How can I get a common mutually exclusive group with its own title/description in the help message of a subcommand?

It was noted in the comments to my old answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45602952/14708097, the parents mechanism does not handle this kind of nesting of groups.  You are trying to use a mix of features that has not received much attention from argparse (volunteer) developers.

TLDR - the parents function does not preserve the nesting of the mutually_exclusive actions.  Parsing should work as expected, but the help display is incomplete.
A simpler example - a simple parser and parent:
In [44]: p1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    ...: g1=p1.add_argument_group('foobar')
    ...: g12 = g1.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    ...: g12.add_argument('-f')
    ...: g12.add_argument('-g');

In [45]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[p1])

In [46]: p1.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-f F | -g G]

foobar:
  -f F
  -g G

In [47]: p.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-f F | -g G]

options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -f F
  -g G

It took a bit of searching to identify what's different between the two parsers.
When p1 was copied over to p, all argument_groups were created:
In [51]: [g.title for g in p1._action_groups]
Out[51]: ['positional arguments', 'options', 'foobar']

In [52]: [g.title for g in p._action_groups]
Out[52]: ['positional arguments', 'options', 'foobar']

Actions were also copied (by reference), but nested actions were not registered with the 'foobar' group:
In [53]: [a.dest for a in p1._action_groups[-1]._group_actions]
Out[53]: ['f', 'g']

In [54]: [a.dest for a in p._action_groups[-1]._group_actions]
Out[54]: []

'f' and 'g' were put in the 'options' group instead of the 'foobar' one.
In [61]: [a.dest for a in p._action_groups[-2]._group_actions]
Out[61]: ['help', 'f', 'g']

'f' and 'g' are present in the primarly list of actions used in parsing:
In [58]: [a.dest for a in p._actions]
Out[58]: ['help', 'f', 'g']

and in the mutuall_exclusive_group:
In [59]: [a.dest for a in p._mutually_exclusive_groups[0]._group_actions]
Out[59]: ['f', 'g']

So parsing should work fine.  It's just the help formmater that can't see the 'foobar' nesting.
In general nesting groups is not well developed.  The ability to put a mutually_exclusive_group in an argument_group for help purposes is allowed - but it's more of an accidental feature than an intentional thing.
Other nesting, such as trying to put argument_groups within a mutually_exclusive_group has not worked as users want, and has now been disallowed.  Same for putting MXG within MXG.
This bug could be written up as an github issue (if it hasn't already been), but I wouldn't expect any fast action.  It doesn't have a dedicated (much less paid) group of developers :)

The answer is very similar to this answer: mutually exclusive argument groups don't affect help output whatsoever, only the actual parsing. Additionally, argument groups (non-mutually exclusive) only affect help message output, and not parsing.
I have serious issues with how argparse handles argument groups and especially mutually exclusive argument groups. I highly recommend abandoning argparse in favor of a better library like docopt, which all my projects now use. It's simpler (by being declarative instead of imperative) and enables having documentation as code. Another great alternative is click, although that one is a bit more complicated. docopt will likely handle your exact use case, and the best part is the help output is exactly as you write it.

docopt is no longer maintained?

Oh wow, that’s new. It now points to a maintained version of the project though, so my point holds.
